# accessing elements of locateall pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I don't understand why I am getting these results. I'm trying to access the coordinates of objects I find with pyautogui. here's my code:

```
import pyautogui
test = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('radiobutton.png', grayscale=True, region=(855,550, 30, 400))
print(test)
print(list(test))
print("length of list:",len(list(test)))
for item in test:
    print("looped")
[x[0] for x in list(test)]
```

and the output I receive from this code:

```
<generator object _locateAll_python at 0x000000000B7A8888>
[(859, 551, 24, 24), (859, 580, 24, 24), (859, 609, 24, 24), (859, 638, 24, 24)]
length of list: 0
```

I would like to be able to access the numbers specifically, for example: 859 or 551.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

must be in line for some reason.

```
radios = list(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('radiobutton.png', grayscale=True, region=(855,475, 30, 400)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood what problem you are exactly facing in accessing individual elements :

Check if the below code helps :

```
co_list = list(test)
print(co_list)
print("length of list:", len(co_list))
first_point_list = [x[0] for x in co_list]
print (first_point_list)  # gives you first element of the list
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks. it has to be in line, not sure why. doesn't make sense. reality is a lie.